# PostgreSQL - Max value for each id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get max value of exam_id from table exams for each protege.

```
proteges

 protege_id | protege_patron | protege_firstname | protege_lastname
------------+----------------+-------------------+------------------
          1 |              1 | Andrzej           | Maniek
          2 |              1 | Anna              | Maj
          3 |              1 | Joanna            | Jankowska
```

```
exams

 exam_id | exam_protege | exam_weight | exam_glucose | exam_pressure
---------+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------
       1 |            1 | 84          | 3ml          | 123/84
       2 |            1 | 99          | 23ml         | 124/72
       3 |            2 | 99          | 23ml         | 124/72
       4 |            3 | 94          | 23ml         | 124/72
```

First I've tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT protege_patron, exams.* 
FROM exams INNER JOIN proteges ON protege_id = exam_protege 
WHERE exam_id = (SELECT MAX(exam_id) FROM exams WHERE protege_patron = 1);
```

and the output was:

```
 protege_patron | exam_id | exam_protege | exam_weight | exam_glucose | exam_pressure
----------------+---------+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------
              1 |       4 |            3 | 94          | 23ml         | 124/72
(1 row)
```

After trying `SELECT protege_firstname, protege_lastname, MAX (exam_id) FROM exams JOIN proteges ON protege_id = exam_protege GROUP BY protege_id;` the output is:

```
 protege_firstname | protege_lastname | max
-------------------+------------------+-----
 Andrzej           | Maniek           |   2
 Anna              | Maj              |   3
 Joanna            | Jankowska        |   4
(3 rows)
```

So, logical way was to add more things like `exam_weight`
That's what I did :

```
SELECT protege_firstname, protege_lastname, exam_weight, MAX (exam_id) FROM exams JOIN proteges ON protege_id = exam_protege GROUP BY protege_id;
ERROR:  column "exams.exam_weight" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select protege_firstname, protege_lastname, exam_weight, MAX...
                                                    ^
```

Atm I don't know how to fix that. Tried distinct, read some about aggregate functions... Is there any way to do that? All I want to do is to JOIN two tables and for each protege select all of his values and values of his exam with max exam_id...

Answer (score 1):

You can to use `distinct on`.  I think the logic is:

```
select distinct on (exam_protege) e.*
from exams e
order by exam_protege, exam_id desc;
```

You can, of course also bring in the protege information using a `join`:

```
select distinct on (exam_protege) e.*, p.*
from exams e join
     protege p
     on e.exam_protege = p.protege_id
order by exam_protege, exam_id desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
select * from
(
  select max(exam_id) maxexamid, exam_protege from exams group by exam_protege
) as maxexams  
inner join proteges p
    on maxexams.exam_protege = p.protege_id
inner join exams e 
    on e.exam_id = maxexams.maxexamid
```